# does gridgain distributed queue supports transaction?

Tags: gridgain

Trying to use transaction with distributed queue in gridgain. Didn't find anything in the documentation or Java Doc.

If it is supported, can someone share some sample code? I tried the following code and it doesn't seem to work.

here is my test code:

```
        GridCache<Object, Object> cache = g.cache("myCache");
        GridCacheDataStructures dataStruct = cache.dataStructures();

        GridCacheQueue<String> queue = dataStruct.queue("myQueue", 0, false, true);

        GridCacheTx tx = cache.txStart();

        .....queue.poll()...etc...

        tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No, GridGain queue operations, although transactional/atomic themselves, currently cannot participate in user transactions.

However, as far as I know, this should not be that hard to support and will be added in the nearest future.